# Succinct DNG Header information?

Tags: java, import, converters, dng

I want to write my own DNG file importer and converter (I need to essentially be able to prove it works in a certain way, so my best bet is to do it myself), but I'm struggling to find any details on the header file. I thought the point of DNG was to be openly documented?

The essential info I need is the byte offsets of each field of metadata and the byte offset of the raw data itself. Similar to [this](http://mathmatrix.narod.ru/Wavefmt.html). Unfortunately so far all I've found is the official adobe documentation which is a 90+ page PDF that mostly bangs on about best practices and what released readers should or should not do, which is not all that helpful.

Is this the best resource out there or is there a more succinct version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As read in [DNG Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/dng_spec.pdf) page 11 Chapter 2 "DNG Format Overview" :

> This section describes the DNG format. As an extension of the TIFF 6.0
>   format, DNG should  follow all the formatting rules for TIFF 6.0. For
>   more information, refer to the TIFF 6.0  specification.

So here are the [TIFF 6.0 Specs](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf) where you could read, page 13, "Section 2: TIFF Structure", a description of the TIFF header.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how I missed that. I was scanning the contents section and looked through any pages that looked promising. I must have missed the link. Thanks!